# How to integrate two applications using single sign on

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

I am having a .net/Java application (application1) in which I have to integrate a service which I have it on another application (application2) which has been designed using Java and important thing is that the user who logged in application1 should be maintained in appliation2.

I know CAS authentication can be used as a solution but I am not sure how this can be achieved if any idea on this kindly share.

Comment: So Application 1 is .net and the second application is in Java. The end user authenticates in the .net application and you want to propagate the rights down Java ? i.e. The end user may have the Admin role and should be able to do special things in the Java application ?

Answer (score 0):

CAS is the best choice for token based single sign on purpose and it is secured one also. CAS will available as a .war file format, you just need to deploy it any server like tomcat, now CAS will work as a centralized authentication system. 
From your applications .Net/ Java you have to import CAS client libraries, and do the xml configurations for login , logout and redirection purpose. Like this the same one you have to repeat for  other application (app2) also.

Based on your requirement may be the first application will be the parent one so cas related token tables you need to implement in your  Parent application DB. in this case second application level no need to check for the password, cas will authenticate with the token generetd by the first application.

If you want CAS should be your parent application In the CAS user data base you should have all login details of users like username and password ect. once cas login is done, you have to provide any buttons or links to open other applications, by using the cas client libraries other applications also will get authenticate if the user name is there in their Data base.

for example refer : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html