# How to achieve single sign on？

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

Now i have to accomplish the java interface （controller）.
But i don not know to use param (the ticket) and get info from
the param.The ticket is secret key produced by center authentication server.
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The similar question is already been answered in stack overflow check the below link 
[How to integrate two applications using single sign on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920100/how-to-integrate-two-applications-using-single-sign-on/34946862#34946862). hope this will give some hints to you.